# Sending "form" details to SQL database via PHP, but need to send details in CORRECT format

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a "form" in PHP and can view the result on my browser by typing in form.php. One part of the code (the code shown below is in a highly truncated form) deals with email verification:

```
<?php
  if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
     .........
     $dateErr = "Invalid date format";
  }
?>
```

If the user types in an email in the wrong format, a warning is generated. I have another PHP file called link.php, which accepts the details that a user has typed into the form and then transfers them to a SQL database (only PART of the code is shown here):

```
<?php  //link.php
    $con=mysqli_connect("host_name","user_name","passwd","db_name");
    ...........
    $mail = ....($con, $_POST['mail']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO table_name (mail,......)
          VALUES (...............)";
 ?>
```

I have entered an email deliberately written in the wrong format, and it appears in the SQL database -- which is not what I want. Yes, my code tells me when an email is written in the wrong format, but that doesn't stop the wrongly written email from ending up on my database. Could one of you PHP experts advice me about how I can write a piece of code which will PREVENT an email written in the wrong format from ever reaching the SQL database? And where does that piece of code go? In "form.php" or in "link.php"?

Comment: Put it in an "if" block. If it fails don't execute the query..

Comment: Since I'm an absolute beginner, may I ask you what exactly that "if" block looks like and where does it go?

Comment: How do you call the code that validates the email?? That woudl probably be the most useful info

Comment: Just put it in the answer. An "if" statement is one of the most basic parts of writing a program. I would suggest you read up on php further before attempting to create an entire program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($_POST['mail']))
    $mail=strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['mail']));
else
   echo "No email provided";


if(isset($mail)){
    if (!filter_var($mail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
         echo "Email is in invalid format";
    }else{
         $con=mysqli_connect("host_name","user_name","passwd","db_name");
         $sql="INSERT INTO table_name (mail,......)
                           VALUES (...............)";
    } 
}
```

Comment: OK, understood. Most appreciated.